# Plotting time series in kibana or alternatives

Tags: graph, elasticsearch, logstash, scatter-plot, kibana

After having implemented the logstash,elasticsearch,kibana stack for visualizing log files, i have realized that kibana only displays histograms and it is [not plotting every single point](https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/978).

My log files are generated once a day and i am interested in looking at every event and not just aggregates (mean,min,max or total).

I could just use excel but I do want to keep the nice search abilities of elasticsearch and the auto updates of data which logstash forwards to elasticsearch. What other tools would you recommend for plotting simple graphs on top of elasticsearch?

I have tried hacking kibana so that the x-time axis is set to an interval of 1 minute. But it's messy since there is other data[image] from different channels for the same day.

Here is a truncated snapshot of my data

```
> 2014-09-26_10-08-13 Algorithm#1 Threshold#1 1.00000 6.70134 
> 2014-09-26_10-08-14 Algorithm#1 Threshold#2 1.00000 6.70134 
> 2014-09-26_10-08-22 Algorithm#2 Threshold#1 0.23913 3.00928 
> 2014-09-26_10-08-46 Algorithm#2 Threshold#2 1.00000 6.69213 
> 2014-09-26_10-08-47 Algorithm#3 Threshold#1   1.00000 6.69217 
> 2014-09-26_10-08-47 Algorithm#3 Threshold#2   1.00000 6.69657
```

Right now for 09/26 all 6 points are plotted
The first numeric field is say performance and second is accuracy
Say I am plotting accuracy vs time (1 minute intervals over days).

I want to separately view each algorithms accuracy over time
I use the query "Algorithm#1" and/or "Threshold#1"
but I keep seeing all six points.

I could be doing the query wrong in which case what is the correct query/filter?

Comment: You could always present all your events in kibana table panel. Just out of curiosity, why do you need to plot every single point?

Comment: The log files are generated once a day with about 4-5 new rows and about 20 columns. It's not that much data and we do want to see every result as it is very specific information about the performance of our api. The generated log file is a .txt file so just viewing it in table format is not very helpful.

Comment: So in a single day you have about 4 - 5 events? If that so, and assuming the events are spread in granular enough resolution, you should be able to find a proper zoom level with kibana histogram that will you show you your entire plot of that day. It's simpler than it sounds...

Comment: I have tried that. Changed the time interval resolution to 1 minute. Two problems, first the y axis does not display floats. so 4.834 and 4.911 are both marked as 5. But the difference is crucial for us.Second, I cannot query and display by specific types. The 4 events logged each day come from 4 specific channels.

Comment: Updated the question section with an image of the histogram. As you can see there is a lot of empty space on the x-axis since i am looking at 1m intervals over days. If it was a scatter plot, the graph would be concise.

Comment: I don't really understand what are you trying to do. First, you say that "its messy since there is other data", but you control what is displayed on the histogram (what queries and what fields), so you can make it "less messy" if you wish. Secondly, judging from the image, it seems that indeed every single even (out of the 4 or 5) is displayed clearly. If you were to zoom on a single day, it would even be more clear, but if you're going to plot many days, than you're in danger of aggregation. Third, what do you mean by "4 specific channels" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62007/discussion-between-user1411110-and-roman).